# Filtering Information in A Report Using VBA-Access - Finding the next avaliable null field

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to organize information in a report in a certain way
I have 9 fields that will be used to store the label for the information
and another 9 fields that store the actual value of the information.
Whenever a field is full, I want it to place the information in the next available field. So that there will be no blank fields in between information.

The issue is that when trying to run this code which triggers two functions,  it is not updating the report I referenced to in the two functions, nor is it pulling information from SpecSheetQuery, and I can't figure out why. My guess is that I'm not referencing the information correctly. I also have to figure out how to run this code individually on each record.

```
Private Sub Detail_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
 Servings = DLookup("[servings]", "SpecSheetQuery")
 Calories = DLookup("[calories]", "SpecSheetQuery")


 If Not IsEmpty(Servings) Then
  OpenSlot ("Servings")
  OpenFact (Servings)
 End If
 
 If Not IsEmpty(Calories) Then
  OpenSlot ("Calories")
  OpenFact (Calories)
 End If

End Sub
```

OpenSlot function, puts title/label of information into field1 ( which is a field on the report) on the first null/empty field. so that no space is left blank.

```
Option Compare Database

Option Explicit

Public Function OpenSlot(Slot As String)


Debug.Print Reports!SpecSheet!field1.Value

If Reports!SpecSheet!field1.Value = Null Then
 Debug.Print "Slot1"
 Slot = Reports!SpecSheet!field1.Value
Debug.Print Reports!SpecSheet!field1.Value

ElseIf Reports!SpecSheet!field2.Value = Null Then
 Reports!SpecSheet!field2.Value = Slot
End If

End Function
```

OpenFact function, puts fact into nut1 ( which is a field on the report) on the first null/empty field. so that no space is left blank.

```
Public Function OpenFact(fact As String)


If Reports!SpecSheet!nut1.Value = Null Then
 Reports!SpecSheet!nut1.Value = fact
Debug.Print Reports!SpecSheet!nut1.Value

ElseIf Reports!SpecSheet!nut2.Value = Null Then
 Reports!SpecSheet!nut2.Value = fact
End If

End Function
```

I'm trying to store this information into this report.
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: My recommendation would be to do it by pre-generating the results in a temporary table, instead of trying to do it on the OnFormat event. There are many limitations on what Access can and can't do during specific events that you can bypass that way. A big advantage of that is that you get to see exactly what your code generates without worrying if it is an Access event limitation that is causing the issue or a bug in your code.

Comment: To clarify, 'temporary' table is actually permanent, the records are temporary. Records exist only for the process and are deleted when completed.

Comment: Thats a really good idea, thanks I'll give it a shot.